# how to allow to type gujarati language in input box in angular 2.?

Tags: md2

I am using md2  library for my text-box. I want that input box allow me to type data in Gujarati language.I google it for this requirement but find no page for this requirement. Any help is very thankfull for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1 
try this! If i does not work post i in the comments section!

Comment: It does not work as per mine requirement.already go through this issue.